# Put using axios works only on postman

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm using axios to update a collection when the user insert a new registry.
So I send the object updated to update the collection on mongodb.

```
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Control className='input-field' type="text" placeholder="Insert a registry"
              ref={inputRef}
              onChange={props.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={event => {
                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                  let elemento = {}
                  elemento.description = inputRef.current.value
                  elemento.cardID = "1"
                  props.list[0].cards.push(elemento)
                  props.handleAdd(props.cardID, JSON.stringify(props.list))
                  event.target.value = ''
                  inputRef.current.focus()
                  event.preventDefault()
                }
              }}
            />
          </Form.Group>
      </Form>
```

For example, that's my original array:

```
{
    "_id": "5d78d065ad06c71d4714156c",
    "name": "canvas01\n",
    "__v": 0,
    "cards": [
        {
            "description": "parceiro1",
            "cardID": "1",
            "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d4714157a",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
        },
        {
            "description": "atividade1",
            "cardID": "2",
            "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d47141579",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-09-11T10:45:57.984Z"
}
```

That's the same array but with a new registry inserted by user.

```
{
    "_id": "5d78d065ad06c71d4714156c",
    "name": "canvas01\n",
    "__v": 0,
    "cards": [
        {
            "description": "parceiro1",
            "cardID": "1",
            "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d4714157a",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
        },
        {
            "description": "atividade1",
            "cardID": "2",
            "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d47141579",
            "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
        },
        {
            "description": "new registry",
            "cardID": "1"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-09-11T10:45:57.984Z"
}
```

To update the collection, I'm using on react side this function:

```
handleAdd = (cardID, updateData) => {
    axios({
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      method: 'put',
      url: URL+'/_id',
      data: updateData
    }).then(resp => {
      this.refresh()
    }
    )
  }
```

It's not return an error, but it's not update my collection in mongodb

`console.log(updateData)` returns me it:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d78d065ad06c71d4714156c",
        "name": "canvas01\n",
        "__v": 0,
        "cards": [
            {
                "description": "parceiro1",
                "cardID": "1",
                "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d4714157a",
                "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
            },
            {
                "description": "atividade1",
                "cardID": "2",
                "_id": "5d78d995ad06c71d47141579",
                "createdAt": "2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"
            },
            {
                "description": "parceiro2",
                "cardID": "1"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2019-09-11T10:45:57.984Z"
    }
]
```

If I get this result, remove the external brackets and submit by postman, it works well.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the third one in the list?

Comment: I'm trying to update the collection with the new registry (third one) inserted by user

Comment: But right now you can't see the third user? But you said above that the response has the third user added to it?

Comment: sorry, what do u mean with third one or third user?

Comment: You're saying that even after the api call, you see only two users ?

Comment: nope, two cards. And I want to update to 3 cards when the user insert the new registry

Comment: Can you check the put request's body in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools with F12?

Comment: I check it out and for some reason it seems that is not sending the object with the new registry inserted by user: `{"_id":"5d78d065ad06c71d4714156c","name":"canvas01\n","__v":0,"cards":[{"description":"parceiro1","cardID":"1","_id":"5d78d995ad06c71d4714157a","createdAt":"2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"},{"description":"atividade1","cardID":"2","_id":"5d78d995ad06c71d47141579","createdAt":"2019-09-11T11:25:09.329Z"}],"createdAt":"2019-09-11T10:45:57.984Z"}`

Comment: So I see 2 card in this request body, it seems you don't correctly generating the request body.

Comment: exactly..that's what I detected after u said to check the request body. Maybe my axios request is not correct.